# How to show children and grandchildren product categories with hierarchy?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-theming

The default catalog WooCommerce setting 'show subcategories' inside of each product category template is not enough.
I need to show all lower level categories inside the first level category with hierarchy, not only the second level - the third too.
I tried many methods, most of them show only one level of subcategories too.  That one shows grandparents, but it shows them without hierarchy - the third level categories look like the second level.

```
add_shortcode('child_category_list', 'get_child_category_list');

function get_child_category_list(){
    ob_start();
    
    // Only on product parent category pages
    if( is_product_category() ) {
        $parent = get_queried_object();

        $categories = get_term_children( $parent->term_id, 'product_cat' ); 
        if ( $categories && ! is_wp_error( $categories ) ) : 

            echo '<ul>';
            echo    '<li>';
            echo        '<a href="'.get_term_link ($parent->term_id, 'product_cat').'">'.$parent->name.'</a>';
            echo        '<ul>';
            foreach($categories as $category) :
                        $term = get_term( $category, 'product_cat' );
                        echo '<li>';
                        echo '<a href="'.get_term_link($term).'" >';
                        echo $term->name;
                        echo '</a>';
                        echo '</li>';
            endforeach;
            echo        '</ul>';
            echo    '<li>';
            echo '</ul>';

        endif;
    }
    return ob_get_clean();
}
```

I place it to taxonomy-product-cat.php template instead of wc_get_template( 'archive-product.php' );
How lo let the loop know about the hierarchy?

Answer (score 0):

this works exactly as you mention in a question

my answer mainly works on [wp_list_categories()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_list_categories/) (Read documentation of it for better understanding)

```
<?php
add_shortcode('display_child_category_list', 'get_child_category_list_shortcode_func');
function get_child_category_list_shortcode_func() {
    ob_start();

    // Check if the current page is a product category
    if ( is_product_category() ) {
        // Get the parent category object
        $parent_category = get_queried_object();

        $parent_id = array( $parent_category->term_taxonomy_id );

        // Get the IDs of the children categories
        $children_ids = get_term_children( $parent_id, 'product_cat' );

        // If there are children categories, display them in a list
        if ( $children_ids && ! is_wp_error( $children_ids ) ) {

            $parent_and_children_ids = array_merge( $parent_id, $children_ids );

            // Display the list of product categories
            wp_list_categories( array(
                'taxonomy'          => 'product_cat',
                'term_taxonomy_id'  => $parent_and_children_ids,
                'orderby'           => 'term_id',
                'order'             => 'ASC',
                'hide_empty'        => false,
                'depth'             => false,
                'title_li'          => '',
            ) );
        }
    }
    return ob_get_clean();
}
```

let me know in the comments, if i miss understood something or anything else